# Why can my UDP socket handle at most 12 packets before dropping them

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

So I've been working on a UDP server-client program in Python (using Ubuntu, in the event that it's relevant). Right now, I've got an implementation to mitigate packet loss, by essentially having the client acknowledge received packets before the server sends more. In my attempt to speed up the performance of this transfer, I began sending ACKs less frequently (I was originally ACKing every packet). In my testing, I've found that 12 packets is, for whatever reason, the maximum amount of packets I can guarantee to be delivered. I'm curious as to why 12 is the "magic number" for my socket.

I'm sending packets of 14000 bytes on my local 127.0.0.1 network.
And to test if this was a matter of how many bytes the socket could receive, I attempted to lower the number of bytes/packet, and then increase the number of packets to ACK. So, if 14000*12 = 168000, I tried various combinations of packet size and number of packets that all totaled 168000 bytes. In any case, 12 was still the magic number.

I've tested this on other computers as well, to be sure that it wasn't an issue with the socket buffers, MTU, or other system dependent variable.

**EDIT:**
I've even tried a similar process in a different program. I've been working on rewriting this program, but still keeping the central idea (less frequent ACKs) the same, and 12 still seems to be the "lucky" number.

My code is below:

Client:

```
try:
while(dataChunk):
    if(numRecv >= 12):
        #print "Stuff" 
        sock.settimeout(.1)
        tcp_sock.send("I got 12 packets")
        count +=1
        numRecv = 0
    else:
        actualNumChunks += 1
        numRecv +=1
        f.write(dataChunk)
        sock.settimeout(.1)
        dataChunk, addr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        packID, junkAddr = sock.recvfrom(buf)
        packIDString = str(packID)
        #tcp_sock.send(packIDString)
else:
    print "Data no longer being recv"
except socket.timeout:
    f.close()
    sock.close()
```

Server:

```
for chunk in read_in_chunks(f):
    if(s.sendto(chunk,addr) and s.sendto(str(local_ID),addr)):
        numSent += 1
        '''
        Store the packet being sent in the appropriate spot
        Indices are arranged by packet localID, and each spot contains the packets load (as a string)
        '''
        packetQueue.insert(local_ID,chunk)   

        '''
        Wait on ACK packets from the client
        We will receive these packets over TCP (expecting the unique Packet ID/sequence number)
        We won't send another packet until we've received the ACK from the client
        If, after x seconds, we haven't received an ACK, we will assume packet was lost, and queue it for retransmission
        '''


        if(numSent >= 12):
            conn.settimeout(.05)
            try:
                ACK = conn.recv(tcp_buf)
                if ACK:
                    numSent = 0
                else:
                    print "ACK is NONE!"
            except socket.timeout:
                ACK = None
                print "Socket timed out (after "+str(count) +" loops) because we didn't get an ACK, let's send him some more packets"
                #conn.settimeout(5)
                while (ACK is not "I got 12 packets"):
                    """
                    Continue with the main loop, and send more packets, 
                    until we get something back (i.e. the client got another 12 packets)
                    """
                    bigDataChunk  = packetQueue[local_ID] + packetQueue[local_ID] + packetQueue[local_ID]
                    s.sendto(bigDataChunk, addr)
                    try:
                        ACK = conn.recv(tcp_buf)
                        print "He just ACKed the big ass data chunk: ",ACK
                    except socket.timeout:

                        print "Socket just timed out again..."

                    if ACK:
                        print "This is the ACK: ", ACK
                        break    
                    else:
                        print "Need to send more packets yet"                          
                else:
                    print "We got an ACK: " + ACK

                    '''
                    Compare this ACK (likely the packets received) against what we know we sent. 
                    There is probably some discrepancy that will need to be addressed. That is to say, he is probably missing some
                    packets, and we're gonna have to resend them now, or make a list to send them later
                    '''
            count += 1
            numSent = 0

        local_ID += 1
```

Just as a note to whoever might have an answer to this: I'm really asking out of curiosity. In practice, I'm going to have to tolerate a certain level of packet loss, and then retransmit lost datagrams. However, there comes a point at which only having 12 packets delivered is way too few, even if I did allow for a certain amount of data loss. This program is designed for large file transfers, and I'm going to need to get more than 12 packets consistently (try several thousands), as I can't constantly be asking for packets to be resent.

Thank you

Comment: There appears to be some code missing from the client example.  Even so, the client has a `>= 12` conditional.  If you change this to 13, does 13 become your magic number?

Comment: Changing to another number does not alter results. I also only posted the relevant code

Comment: It might seem like the code you posted is enough, but without a [minimal, complete, and cerifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the likelihood of a definitive answer is greatly reduced.